# How to deal with a question whose answer was different from the original question?

Tags: support

I asked this question, [How to integrate a conditional function?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/how-to-integrate-a-conditional-function), but it turns out, it wasn't a conditional function. And I got the answer I was looking for, but now the question is a misleading label of the real question. What should I do? Rename it?

The only hesitation I have to renaming it is that it also answers the question of whether or not it was a conditional function. Part of my question was to understand what the semicolon means in $f(X;\beta)$. And that got an answer. So if I re-label it, that part is overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut instinct is that you should rename the question to something like "Integrating a piece-wise function and semicolons in function notation".

The only time I foresee the word 'conditional' being relevant in the title is if someone has the same misconception and thinks that's what the semicolon means. But I'm not sure it's a good strategy for the site to keep mislabeled questions on the off-chance that the mislabeling might be exactly what a future user is looking for.

It doesn't look like the body of your question needs changing at all.

Answer (score 2):

If your mistake is representative, let it be. If others have similar thoughts, and also wonder "How to integrate a conditional function", they will find out that - boy, that's actually not what I wanted to ask.

If someone bothers to google "integrating a piece-wise function and semicolons in function notation", probably he already knows the answer.